# convert timestamp to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I used pandas read_excel to load some time data from excel into python and saved in variable `times`. For example, `times[0] = 2020-12-30`, in Excel it's just `2020/12/30`.

Now The type of `times[0]` is `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.

How can I convert it into DateTime? And if possible, can I convert it into a nanosecond?

Comment: A timestamp in pandas specifies date and time, so what do you mean exactly by "*convert it into datetime*"?

Comment: can I have something to combine both? like 2020-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: have a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) - that is exactly what you have.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, the timestamp default value is date and time. Moreover, if you want to get DateTime then use `to_datetime` and To get nanosecond set `unit='ns'`

```
pd.to_datetime(1490195805433502912, unit='ns')
```

**Output**

```
Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45.433502912')
```

Read more datetime [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and to know more about [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html#pandas-to-timedelta), find the link

Comment: pandas read my value as date '2020-12-30' from excel. when I call pd.to_datetime(,unit = 'ns'), the result is still date

Answer (score 1):

If you have a series of times

```
>>> times = pd.Series(pd.date_range('20180310', periods=2))
>>> times
0   2018-03-10
1   2018-03-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can convert the Timestamp entries to datetime using the [`dt.to_pydatetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html) function like so

```py
>>> times.dt.to_pydatetime()
array([datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 11, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

However as per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html) mentions:

***Warning:** Python’s datetime uses microsecond resolution, which is lower than pandas (nanosecond). The values are truncated.*